# How to find the count when only one column is true in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have a table

| category1 | category2 | planA | planB | PlanC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-12-10 | false | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2020-12-10 | true | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2020-12-11 | false | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2020-12-11 | true | 1 | 1 | 0 |

How do I find the no of rows with planA 1 and all other plans 0?. In my actual table, I have 100 plans. So I won't be able to hard code planA=1 and planB=0 and planC=0 etc. I'm looking for a smart solution.
I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You may use:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM yourTable
WHERE planA = 1 AND planB = 0 AND planC = 0;
```

This is probably as good as a pattern as you can get here without using dynamic SQL.  Having hundreds of plan columns might indicate poor table design, and perhaps those plan columns should really exist as a single column with multiple records.

Most SQL functions and operations are set based, with the set being defined as multiple *records* or rows.  So, few SQL functions will do aggregations across arbitrary columns (`GREATEST` and `LEAST`, in some databases, perhaps being exceptions, but even there one must still list out all columns).

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with your data model if you have 100 columns with such similar flags.

For your particular data, you would need a big `WHERE` clause:

```
select count(*)
from t
where a = 1 and b = 0 and c = 0 and . . . ;
```

That said, you should have a table with one row per plan that is available:

```
category1    category2    plan
2020-12-10   false          A
2020-12-10   false          C
2020-12-10   true           A
. . .
```

Only the ones that are present would be in this table.

Then you can do:

```
select category1, category2
from t
group by category1, category2
having count(*) = 1 and min(plan) = 'A';
```

Comment: I think your table with a single column for the plan will work only if the plans are mutually exclusive. That is not the case with my tables

Comment: @Naseef . . . What do you mean "mutually exclusive"?  This is just an alternate representation of the same data you have as flags in a single row.

Comment: The same row can have multiple plans as shown in row 1 and row 4 @Gordon Lintoff

Comment: @Naseef . . . And that is represented by the first two rows of the table in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think conditions is mandatory on SQL query for planB and planC. Maybe you can apply a calculation check as below:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table WHERE planA = 1 AND (planB + planC) <> 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you can use PIVOT in your SQL to change row to columns your output will looks like this

Category1     Category2     name      Pivot
2020-12-10     false          planA    1
2020-12-10     false          planb    0
2020-12-10     false          planc    1
2020-12-10     true           planA    1
2020-12-10     true           planb    0
2020-12-10     true           planc    0
......          ....          ...

Post pivoting you can apply group by and then have sum of Pivot field equal to 1 with other condition filed 'name' = 1